# SSRS Text Box Alignment - Page Footer

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, alignment, footer

I've been struggling with this for a while.
In several of the SSRS reports, the text boxes in the page footer, that contain a user's name and the print date of the report, won't align to the right side of the report (see Page 1 - Page Footer image).  What's weird is that the last page aligns correctly to the far right, as it is set up in the design view (see Last Page - Page Footer image).  I have removed the report user name from the images for security reasons.
Please note, this is not the text alignment inside the box but the box itself.

**Page 1 - Page Footer**
[Page 1 - Page Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a37v.png)

**Last Page - Page Footer**
[Last Page - Page Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHo5I.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A few questions off the top of my head: Have you tried changing the can grow/shrink properties of the text boxes? Have you confirmed the box is not resizing by setting a visible border? Also, is this a single tablix report or does the report width/#of columns etc change at any point?

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield.  I tried changing the can grow/shrink properties without any luck.  There are no visible borders on these two boxes.  Some reports have a dynamic width tablix but the report I just tested has a fixed width tablix.  The two boxes appear fine on the last page, just not the previous pages.  I'm having to modify about 50 reports and so far half are having this issue.  I'm wondering if it's a "design feature" of Visual Studio.

Comment: Try putting a border around the boxes so we can see where they're being placed. That will help show if there's weird padding or margins. Are you using Visual Studio or Report Builder?

Comment: I figured it out by accident and will post an answer.  Thank you for your help Alan Schofield and @RussellFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by accident how to resolve this issue.  I'm wondering if it's a design issue in SSRS and/or Visual Studio 2013.
I expanded the two text boxes on the right all the way to the left and connected them to to additional text boxes I had on the left side of the page.  When I previewed the report the right two text boxes were aligned on to the far right of the page as they should have been.  See image below.

**Footer Textbox Fix**
[Footer Textbox Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dja1e.png)

Thank you everyone for your help!  I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me, SSRS is so odd, why would getting the page number to right align consistently be a problem in 2020?

Comment: I have a textbox in my footer that is visible on every page except the first. This makes the Paging on the right move to the left on the first page. Still haven't figured out fixing this one. Anyone seen this?